# What is the Pulse scheme within Monday.coy? I've tried google, monday api docs, and the monday community all to no avail

Tags: monday.com

I am updating a synchronization with Monday.com.

I'm looking for the scheme to the pulse object, especially in a "mustache" context, what are the elements of pulse?

I've tried searching Monday's API docs and community